# SQLite inserts wrong values. iOS Dev

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am getting familiar with SQLite on iOS. I am trying to do simp user registration, but value for age (NSInteger) always turns to some large negative number like -1073752692.
This is my code for registration:

```
    - (User*) registerUser:(NSString *) firstname
              lastname:(NSString *) lastname
                   age:(NSInteger) Age
                 email:(NSString *) email
              password:(NSString *) password
               picture:(NSString *) picture
{
    User* user = nil;
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO User (firstname, lastname, age, email, password, picture) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%d\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", firstname, lastname, Age, email, password, picture];

    sqlite3_stmt *insert;
    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &insert, NULL);
    if (result == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_step(insert);
        user = [[User alloc]init];
        user.firstname = firstname;
        user.lastname = lastname;
        user.age = Age;
        user.password = password;
        user.picture = picture;
        NSLog(@"Successful registration!");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: insert prepare statement failed: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(self.db));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(insert);
    return user;

}
```

I can't think of why this would happen. I used to work with Postgres a lot and never had such problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is your age variable capitalized? Looks like a type.

Comment: hi, thanks, i made it upper case (for no apparent reason :)

Comment: Note that had you simply NSLogged your `sql` value you would have seen where the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5) says that you should not use `NSInteger` with `%d`.

In any case, to prevent formatting problems like this and SQL injection attacks (any string containing `"` would make your code blow up), you should use parameters:

```
NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO User(firstname,lastname,age,email,password,picture)"
                 " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &insert, NULL);
if (result == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 1, [firstname UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 2, [lastname UTF8String],  -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_int (insert, 3, Age);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 4, [email UTF8String],     -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 5, [password UTF8String],  -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 6, [picture UTF8String],   -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    result = sqlite3_step(insert);
    ...
```

(You also need to check the return value of `sqlite3_step`.)